# Linq и Join: как написать запрос? (и почему я не получаю "прямое произведение" множеств?)

Tags: c#, linq

У меня довольно приличный опыт с SQL, а в Linq я полный профан.

Пока речь идет о fluent syntax и работе с одной последовательностью - вроде всё понятно.

Но при поптыке сделать Join или хотя бы понять синтаксис Join'а я теряюсь.

Я нашел наиболее похожий пример на [CodeRoad](https://coderoad.ru/2767709/Join-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%81-LINQ-%D0%B8-Lambda)

Теперь о моей задаче: есть класс Employer и есть класс Phone. У одного сотрудника может быть несколько телефонов. Нужно вывести список сотрудников с их телефонами.

```
    class Employer {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Phone {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public long EmployerID { get; set; }
    }
```

Я заполняю тестовые таблицы и у меня есть список четырех сотрудников и пяти телефонов:

```
    Employees:
    1   Secretar
    2   Michail
    3   Dmitry
    4   Cleaner

    Phones:
    1   1   401       
    2   1   501       
    3   2   699       
    4   3   520       
    5   3   407
```

В SQL я написал бы примерно такой запрос:

```
    select Employees.Id, Name, ( select STRING_AGG (PhoneNumber, ' ') from Phones where EmployerId=Employees.Id ) from Employees
```

и получил результат, близкий к нужному:

```
    1   Secretar    401        501       
    2   Michail     699       
    3   Dmitry      520        407       
    4   Cleaner     NULL
```

В Linq я написал запрос

```
        // Соединяем людей и их телефоны:
        var s = employees.Join(
            phones,                  // inner sequence
            e => e.ID,               // outerKeySelector
            p => p.ID,               // innerKeySelector
            (e, p) => new { id = e.ID, name = e.Name, phones = p.PhoneNumber })
            .Where( < и тут моя фантазия кончилась... > )
```

И еще один дополнительный вопрос.

Если я в SQL напишу тупой запрос (без WHERE)

```
    select * from Employees, Phones
```

то я получу 20 строк - все возможные комбинации людей и телефонов

Но в Linq если я напишу первую часть своего запроса

```
        var s = employees.Join(
            phones,                  // inner sequence
            e => e.ID,               // outerKeySelector
            p => p.ID,               // innerKeySelector
            (e, p) => new { id = e.ID, name = e.Name, phones = p.PhoneNumber })
```

и сделаю что то типа .ToList(), то мне вернется только кол-во строк, соответсвующее кол-ву людей. Не могли бы Вы объяснить, почему так происходит - я же не написал where, и вроде бы результатом долждно быть "прямое произведение множеств":

[image: linq result]

Comment: *В SQL я написал бы примерно такой запрос* А на LEFT JOIN переписать смогёшь? Тогда отображение в Linq станет элементарным.

Comment: Объединение происходит по селекторам: `e.ID`, `p.ID`. ЗЫ: должно быть `p.EmployerID`.

Comment: зачем писать джлойны руками? У вас на теблице внешний ключ есть? Пишите [правльно модели](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.5.php), оставьте джойны ORM, пусть она за вас их выполняет.

Comment: Большое спасибо за советы! я прошу прощения, но у меня проблема именно с пониманием того, как работает Join в Linq. Отличие от SQL просто выносит мозг. Я пробую сделать Join и не вижу, где нужно написать условие, по кторому осуществляется Join. @Akina - не смогу, потому что у меня нет аналога STRING_AGG()

Comment: Ваша проблема возникает из-за того, что в linq для ef joinы не использоваться почти вообще, вместо этого посмотрите include. Джойны нужны бывают когда нужна связь по не ключевым полям, остальное время include и  lazy loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уважаемый, M.O., по моему, у Вас есть три проблемы, котрые Вы объединили в один вопрос

Попробую расказать о них последовательно.

1. *Синтаксис Join*

По той ссылке, которую Вы привели в вопросе, содержится "ну так себе" русский перевод вопроса с английского SO. Достаточно взять ссылку на coderoad.ru, и подставить тот же ID - шник в ссылку на stackoverflow.com, полчится ссылка на [оригинал вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/join-where-with-linq-and-lambda).

Самое главное заблуждение:

когда Вы пишите, что вторым и третьим параметром Join являются ключи тех коллекций, о которым происходит Join - это не совсем так.

Это - те ключи, по которым как раз эти коллекции и джоинятся! То есть, в Вашем случае, если надо телефоны сопоставлять с людьми по хранящейся в телефоне ссылке EmployerID, то именно так и должно быть написано в третьем параметре Join'а (о чем Вам кратко в комментарии написал Alexander Petrov).

(кстати, это заодно и ответ на вопрос "почему не получается прямого произведения": джоин делается в любом случае, просто либо по правильному набору ключей, либо по неправильному)

Тогда получится такая картина:

```
        var q = employees.
            Join(
            phones,
            e => e.ID,
            p => p.EmployerID,
            (e, p) => new { eid = e.ID, name = e.Name, peid = p.EmployerID, number = p.PhoneNumber }
            );
```

Если это штуку выполнить в чем то вроде [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) (очень рекомендую!) то Вы увидите, что Ваш список правильно сджоинился: там будет 5 элементов, где рядом с человеком написан его телефон. Люди с несколькими телефонами присутствуют в списке несколько раз. Последнего человека (у которого телефона нет) в списке не будет.

Дальше можно поступить так:

можно попробовать сгруппировать:

```
        var q2 = employees.
            Join(
            phones,
            e => e.ID,
            p => p.EmployerID,
            (e, p) => new { eid = e.ID, name = e.Name, peid = p.EmployerID, number = p.PhoneNumber }
            ).
            GroupBy(x => x.eid);
```

Но... на этом месте я предлагаю остановиться, и перейти к проблеме номер два:

2. *fluent синтакс не зря так называется.*

В формате fluent каждое (отделенное от другого точкой) выражение работает как преобразователь, который порождает новый объект.

Именно эта проблема, как я понял, возникла в месте, где "фантазия кончилась".

То есть, обратите внимание на то, как уже после Join'а написан GroupBy: там используются не те поля, которые есть в исходных объектах.

Также, Where здесь нет: всё, что нужно для Join'а - задано в самом Join'е.

3. *Как мне кажется, решение задачи вообще выглядит по другому.*

Вот такое выражение

```
    var list = employees.Select(
      e => new { 
            id=e.ID, 
            name = e.Name, 
            phones = string.Join(", ", phones.Where(p => p.EmployerID == e.ID).Select(p => p.PhoneNumber) ) 
      }).ToList();
```

даёт результат, очень похожий на тот, который выводит Ваш SQL - запрос:

```
    1  Secretar     401, 501
    2  Michail      699
    3  Dmitry       520, 407
    4  Cleaner
```

( забавно, что здесь тоже присутствует слово Join, но это "совсем другой" Join: он просто соединяет в одну строку разные строковые переменнные через запятую )

И финальное замечание: у меня есть сомнения насчет производительтности этого решения - я сам знаю Linq только "постольку-поскольку". Возможно, кто то укажет на недостатки такого решения.

Кстати, сам вопрос оформлен - шикарно! Все бы так...

Comment: Спасибо! Это объяснение - лучше всех, которые мне попадались.